# Multiple radio button groups interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have two groups of radio buttons set up in one form:

```
<li>1&nbsp;<Input type = 'radio' id ='part1no' Name ='part1' value= '0'>No
           <Input type = 'radio' id ='part1yes' Name ='part1'  checked="checked" value= '1'>Yes
</li>
<li>2&nbsp;<Input type = 'radio' id ='part2no' Name ='part2'  value= '0'>No
           <Input type = 'radio' id ='part2yes' Name ='part2' checked="checked" value= '1'>Yes
</li>
```

I'm trying to submit the values of those buttons via this javascript function:

```
var dataString = 'username='+SessionVars.my_username+'&lessonid='+SessionVars.my_lesson_number;

$('#tracking_submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/tracking.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: dataString+'&p1='+$("input[@name=part1]:checked").val()+'&p2='+$("input[@name=part2]:checked").val(),
        success: function(){
            $('#tracking_message').html("Thank you for updating.").fadeIn('slow');              
            setTimeout(function(){$('#tracking_message').fadeOut('slow');},2000);
        }                   
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Issue is that when I check the database, it updates both fields set to the value of the first radio button. If the first ones is set to Yes, both will be set to 1 and if the first one is set to 0, both would be 0. Anyone has any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Don't give two elements the same name of `part1` and likewise with `part2`.

Comment: can you post contents of tracking.php, as its the one causing the problem ( updating the database)

Comment: **@Justin Satyr**: If they're part of a group then you need to use the same name, that's how radios work most of the time. The problem with the HTML code is that it look very messy, with unusual whitespace, caps without any reason...etc

Comment: @Tom this is not in the database, I checked the value on submission, they are the same prior the data being sent out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$("input[@name=part1]:checked").val()` should not have the `@` character. That is XPath syntax, not jQuery selector syntax.

jQuery is probably ignoring that "@attribute" request (since it's invalid), finding all `input`'s, and then `.val()` is returning the first value in the set.